# Top-nav Menu with dropdown panel

Tags: drupal, themes

I am working with bootstrap template and I need to be pointed in the right direction so I can achieve this:

I would like to implement in my website the same top-navbar-menu this website has: https://www.redhat.com/en.

What is the best approach? Possible to know how this is implemented?

What to look for? javascript? jquery? any bootstrap implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Site is using theme with machine name "redhatdotcom". Don't think that you can find more without logging in as admin to site. Probably custom made theme.

Comment: Thought was a custom made theme. Have seen any other template (doesn't matter which cms), has the same function/style as the  redhat.com website top-bar?